# how to disable past dates from datepicker in bootstrab 2.3.2

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to disable past dates from the datepicker using bootstrab 2.3.2. I have tried the following code taken from documents, but now i am still battling with this concept. Can anyone give me some ideas? What is wrong with my code?

```
<div class="input-append date"  data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" >
<input name="date_pick" id="dpd1" type="text"  required style="padding:8px 0 !important">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar sh_black_text"></i></span>
</div>
```

**My Script**

```
$(function(){
            $('.date').datepicker({});
                var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
    })
        });
```

Comment: is this is the plugin are you using? https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

Comment: no its just  a bootstrab 2.3.2 file and calling function.that;s all bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new date object and set it as `startDate` when you initialize the datepickers

Refer this https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#startdate

In your case it is

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    startDate: '-1d'
})
```

like this

Comment: @UdayaRavi  -- I am seeing this line $('.date').datepicker({}); in your sample code. Please update it